# when open connection of URL by Java API it is working fine in development side,but not working on UAT,the error is showing Connection timed out

Tags: java

when open connection of URL by Java API it is working fine in development side,but not working on UAT,the error is showing Connection timed out.Please suggest what to do? 
Here given userID,password proxyip and port are not actual because it is the client url.

```
 package qc.los.util;
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Map;
    import java.util.Properties;
    import java.util.Random;

    import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

    import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

    import qc.dal.DAL;
    import qc.dal.dto.ParameterDTO;
    import qc.los.controller.action.NewProspectAction;
    import qc.sso.util.UserLockingFilter;

        public class Utils {
            protected static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Utils.class);

            public static void main(String[] args) 
            {
                Utils Utilss=new Utils();

                Utilss.sendVerificationCodeToCustomer("","9811937492","myTestras",true,"properhost","properport");
            }


            public String sendVerificationCodeToCustomer(String prospectId,String mobileNumber, String verificationCode, boolean proxyEnabled, String proxyHost, String proxyPort)
            {
                log.info("Start");
                Properties systemSettings = System.getProperties();
                try
                {

                    //UPdated by for user id password
                    String urlStr ="http://www.example.com/SendSMS/sendmsg.php?uname=rahul&pass=rahul&send=Tag&dest="+mobileNumber+"&msg=Your%20verification%20code%20is%20"+verificationCode+"&concat=1";
                    log.info("urlStr  "+urlStr);
                    URL u = new URL (urlStr);

                    log.info("proxyHost and proxyPort  "+proxyHost+"        "+proxyPort);

                    if(proxyEnabled)
                    {
                        log.info("proxyEnabled with proxyHost and proxyPort  "+proxyHost+"        "+proxyPort);
                        systemSettings.put("proxySet", "true");
                        systemSettings.put("proxyHost", proxyHost);
                        systemSettings.put("proxyPort", proxyPort);
                    }

                    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection ();
                    con.setDoInput(true);
                    con.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    log.info("Connection start");
                    con.connect();
                    log.info("Connection connected");
                    InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
                    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                    String line;
                    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer(); 
                    while((line = rd.readLine()) != null) 
                    {
                        response.append(line);
                        response.append("<br>");
                    }
                    rd.close();
                    log.info("End:Message sucessfull with response "+response.toString());
                    return response.toString();
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    String proxySetting = proxyEnabled + ":" + proxyHost + ":" + proxyPort;
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    log.error("exception while sending sms:("+proxySetting+")"+"        "+e.getMessage());
                    return "exception while sending sms:("+proxySetting+")"+e.getMessage();
                }
                finally
                {
                    if(proxyEnabled)
                    {
                        systemSettings.remove("proxySet");
                        systemSettings.remove("proxyHost");
                        systemSettings.remove("proxyPort");
                    }

                    log.info("End");
                }
            }





        }
```

Comment: Is the URL reachable from users computer? Are proxy settings correct? Also, your password is rubbish. Do you want to get your accounts stolen? Because that's how you get your accounts stolen.

Comment: userid and password is proper.The URL reachable from users computer also.but by code it is creating issue.Same is fine for my side.